# Add classes and attributes to all multiple selects in Symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to customize all multiple selects of my application like that :

```
<select class="selectpicker show-tick" data-size="auto">
...
</select>
```

How should I do that?

**EDIT for ncrocfer**

This is my build form method:
This is not complete, lack some stuff...

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('misc')
        ->add('url')
        ->add('attachment', 'file')
        ->add('time_estimated')
        ->add('started_at')
        ->add('finished_at')
        ->add('default')
        ->add('deadline')
        ->add('priority', 'entity', array(
            'class'    => 'LanCrmBundle:TaskPriority',
            'property' => 'title',
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->add('project', 'entity', array(
            'class'    => 'LanCrmBundle:Project',
            'property' => 'title',
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->add('category', 'entity', array(
            'class'    => 'LanCrmBundle:TaskCategory',
            'property' => 'title',
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->add('user', 'entity', array(
            'class'    => 'LanSecurityBundle:User',
            'property' => 'username',
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->add('products', 'entity', array(
            'class'    => 'LanCrmBundle:Product',
            'property' => 'title',
            'multiple' => true
        ))
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `attr` attribute in your form buider :

```
<?php

namespace Foo\BarBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class FooType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('foo', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(0 => 'Option 1', 1 => 'Option 2'),
                'attr' => array('class' => 'selectpicker show-tick', 'data-size' => 'auto'),
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you have a lot of forms like you said in your comment, you can use the [form customization](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html).

Create a new template file :

```
{# src/Foo/BarBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block choice_widget_collapsed %}
{% spaceless %}
    <select {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if multiple %} multiple="multiple"{% endif %} class="selectpicker show-tick" data-size="auto">
        {% if empty_value is not none %}
            <option value="">{{ empty_value|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
        {% endif %}
        {% if preferred_choices|length > 0 %}
            {% set options = preferred_choices %}
            {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
            {% if choices|length > 0 and separator is not none %}
                <option disabled="disabled">{{ separator }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set options = choices %}
        {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
    </select>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_collapsed %}
```

Then import your template inside your application configuration :

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'FooBarBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

The change will be effective on all your `select`.

Comment: I know this method but it is too time consuming. I've got a lot of forms. I saw something about creating a **fields.html.twig** file and customizing each specific input type or just one (my case). But I can't find great examples.

Comment: That's really strange, it doesn't work as I expected. It works only on time and datetime, not on my select and multi select from a formtype with entity as second params like that ->add('', 'entity', ...)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it works for time, date or datetime select but not for entity builders.


http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1393841004.png

I will edit my first post with my form builder code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `attr` attribute in `FormBuilder`:

```
'attr' => array('class'=>'selectpicker show-tick', 'data-size'=>'auto')
```